# General Approach and Intuition to Calculus based problems in Physics

Tags: mathematics

I've done a calculus-based course in Mechanics, Electromagnetism and at the moment I'm studying Strengths of Materials. Time and again, one is faced with problems where Integration is used to sum up charges, electric field vectors etc. Somehow, I find it hard to approach these problems. In general I find myself confronted with two main issues as I am solving such problems:

1) How should one determine whether the problem at hand requires the use of calculus, in particular integration ?

2) Which variable or quantity should be made infinitesimly small?

To further narrow the scope of the question: Consider the following problem:

> A bar uniformly tapering from a diameter $D_1$ at one end to a diameter $D_2$ at the other end is shown in the Figure below. Let P be the Axile Tensile load on the bar, E be the Young's Modulus and L be the total length of the bar, then find the total extension in the bar.

[image]

It is not necessary, but would be great if you could  take this problem into account while answering the aforementioned questions.

Comment: I think these type of problems can be more practically solved by Finite element methods rather than calculus. Calculus can only give solutions for relatively simpler problems.

Answer (score 1):

For any given physics problem, there will be an equation that describes the phenomenon that is being modeled.  Whatever is varying in the problem will affect the phenomenon that you are interested in.  The mathematical relationship between what is varying and the phenomenon of interest will determine whether or not the problem requires integration.

To be more specific, there are several questions and answers that apply to the problem of the tapered rod:

1) Q: What is varying?  A: The radius of the rod.
2) Q: What is the phenomenon of interest?  A: The stretch of the rod.
3) Q: What variable in the problem affects stretch of the rod?
   A: The tensile strength of the rod when a given load is applied.
4) Q: What variable affects tensile strength of the rod?
   A: The cross-sectional area of the rod.
5) Q: How are cross-sectional area and radius related?  A: Area = pi * r^2.

Such "pre-analysis" should lead to the conclusion that the rod with a continuously varying radius can be approximately by a series of thin, constant radius cylinders that are "welded" end to end.  Each constant radius cylinder has a supposedly constant tensile strength, with a resulting stretch.  If you sum up the stretch from each short cylinder, you arrive at the desired answer.

Obviously, the shorter that each constant-radius cylinder is, the better the approximation of the problem at hand.  Thus, an infinite number of these cylinders, of infinitesimal thickness dx (as shown in your drawing), will arrive at the desired answer.  This means that an integral is required, where the variable of integration is dx.

Every problem that you work should involve some type of analysis similar to that shown above.  The intuition required to ask the right questions only comes from working a lot of varied problems.  Thus, one quick posting and answer to the physics stack exchange, or merely understanding the math required to solve physics and engineering problems, is a necessary but insufficient condition for acquiring the intuition to set up these problems.  The ONLY way to get the required intuition necessarily requires a LOT of time spent working and thinking about a large variety of problems.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How should one determine whether the problem at hand requires the use of calculus, in particular integration ?

When the problem includes variations, we need calculus (integral and derivative).

> 2) Which variable or quantity should be made infinitesimally small?

The variable(s) that variations of problem occur along it.

---

In your case, the problem includes variations because of variation of diameter, and variation of diameter occurs along **length** of the bar.